# How to deal with Misplaced View warning in Xcode storyboards?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I am trying to change the position of a `UIScrollView` that is inside a `UIView`, but whenever I change its position I get a warning which says that "Frame for scroll view will be different at run time" (see image below). How do I handle this properly?

[image]

`UIScrollView` Constraints:

[image]

`UIView` inside `UIScrollView` constraints:

[image]

Here I am trying to move the `UIScrollView` inside the root `UIView`.

[image]

Comment: can you able to share code or constraint you have applied

Comment: I've updated my post showing the constraints, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning simply means that where you have the view positioned in canvas (aka where you have dragged the view to in Xcode's ui editor), does not match the location where the view will be positioned when the app is running, based on the constraints you've set.

First check that your constraints are correct, and that they will cause the view to appear where you want at run time.

If the constraints are correct, and the view just needs to be repositioned in the storyboard you can click on the view then go to Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Update Frames. Then Xcode will automatically update the position of the view in canvas based on the existing constraints.

Comment: Hello, thank you and it worked but the scroll view is now no longer scrollable after doing this. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Check contentSize of ScrollView it must be less then bounds of scrollView. after  Update Frames try check frame of your scrollview.

Comment: Hard to tell, that's a different question.

Comment: If your music sheet is what is scrolling in the scroll view. Make sure it is bigger than the scroll view. There are multiple ways of doing that. You can try making sure that the constraints on your Labels to the Music sheet are such that they force the music sheet to be bigger than the scroll view in the direction you want it to scroll